# How to interpret Application Verifier Logs

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce

Code of Application Verifier
 `enter code here`:
     Potential leak.     1 items ( 1000 bytes) at 0x2f356b78
     (nk.exe:80077408) Callstack:
     (nk.exe:80077408) Leaked items:
     (nk.exe:80077408)    0x001d3860    1000 bytes, thread: 0x769eabe6, checkpoint 0
     (nk.exe:80077408)       Total: 1000 bytes

```
  Above is the Application verifier log for an application.How to interpret it?
  WHat is the difference between 0x2f356b78
  and  0x001d3860.
```

Answer (score 0):

Those values are addresses. They indicate where the leak occurred. The easiest way to translate those values in to something useful is to point App Verifier to the PDB file for your application.

This article describes how to use App Verifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446904.aspx